# Determine instantaneous phase from two shifted periodic signals with unknown offset

Tags: python, periodicity, periodic-processing

I have two periodic noisy signals which depend on a constantly increasing reference angle. The two signals are shifted by 90 degrees and one of them has an unknown varying offset. Two sample signals like this can be generated using a simple python code:

```
instantaneous_phase=np.linspace(0,6*np.pi,1000) % (2*np.pi)

unknown_offset=np.linspace(0,1,1000)

signal1=np.sin(instantaneous_phase) + ((np.random.rand(1000))-0.5)/10
signal2=np.cos(instantaneous_phase) + ((np.random.rand(1000))-0.5)/10 + unknown_offset
```

Giving something like:

[image]

I need to reconstruct `instantaneous_phase`, using only `signal1` and `signal2`. Is this possible? I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: When you say "determine quadrant", do you really mean "determine frequency/phase", or something like that?  Can you clarify what's known, and what isn't known?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you comment. I updated the question title - hope it makes more sense now. Known parameters are `signal1` and `signal2`, unknown is `instantaneous_phase`, which I need to reconstruct.